# Meaning of "harmonic"

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, terminology, anharmonic-oscillators

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the term "harmonic". IE, appearing in following sentence of [Fluctuation-dissipation relations for stochastic gradient descent](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00004)

> The second relation (FDR2) further helps us determine the properties
> of the loss function landscape, including the strength of its Hessian
> and the degree of anharmonicity, i.e., the deviation from the
> idealized harmonic limit of a quadratic loss surface and a constant
> noise matrix.

What is the meaning of "harmonic limit" here?

Also, is it appropriate to term "harmonic approximation" to refer to a method which uses Gaussian-like approximation? (ie, assumes that cumulants of rank-3 and above are zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the equivalence between the loss surface (or loss function) and a physical potential then the "harmonic limit" here is the one of a Brownian evolution into a harmonic (or quadratic) potential. That means the stochastic gradient views as a stochastic process is the same than the evolution of a particle driven by a thermal noise into a quadratic potential.

As the solution of the Fokker-Planck equation associated with such evolution are actually Gaussian, it could be thought as a Gaussian-like approximation. But the approximation here is really on the loss function.